# Check what command was used inside a custom Rails 3 generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How can you tell if a `generate` or `destroy` command has been used to invoke a custom generator?

In Rails 2 you could do this:

```
if options[:command] == :destroy
  ...
end
```

I want to print out some helpful information, but only when `rails generate` has been called, not when `rails destroy` is called:

```
if is_generating
  puts "You're generated something!"
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: this seems pointless... but if you really want to http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3 should set you on track

Comment: @jvatic In what way is this pointless? I don't think notifications are what I'm after. I just want to know what type of generation action is being run. Specifically, are we currently generating files or deleting them. That way I can print out information to the user that says something like "You now need to add file 'XYZ.css' to app/views/layouts/application.html.erb". (That's not exactly what I'm doing, but that's the gist of it.)

Comment: I have the same question. When rails generate'ing, I add a config entry. When destroying, I remove a config entry. I need to know how to know when to add the entry (when running rails generatate ...) as opposed to when to remove the config entry (when running rails destroy ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the generator class's behavior. It seems you should get either :invoke for generate or :revoke for destroy. For example, I added this:

```
class PatternGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  def echo_behavior
    p "generate? #{generating?}"
    p "destroying? #{destroying?}"
  end

  protected

  def generating?
    :invoke == behavior
  end

  def destroying?
    :revoke == behavior
  end  
end
```

Running this, I get:

```
younker % rails g pattern foo      
"generate? true"
"destroying? false"
younker % rails destroy pattern foo
"generate? false"
"destroying? true"
```

Seems to work and makes sense, so that's my final answer.

Comment: Where is this `behavior` method?  Where are these `:invoke` and `:revoke` symbols defined?

Comment: @jordanpg, the behavior is set to :invoke or :revoke in rails [generate.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b0f8355d2813c375bf9242071131e8c5a350bcf0/railties/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb) and [destroy.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b0f8355d2813c375bf9242071131e8c5a350bcf0/railties/lib/rails/commands/destroy.rb). In retrospect, monkey patching Rails::Generators may have been a bit cleaner. Hope this helps.